# Error while deploying application: persistentvolumeclaims already exists

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, openshift, kompose

I have a docker application which uses docker-compose, i want to deploy the project in openshift-3, so i'm using  [kompose](https://kompose.io/).
Here is my docker-compose file:-

```
version: '3'

services:
  katana-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *****
      POSTGRES_USER: *****
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - katana-db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile_uwsgi
    image: warrior_deployment_backend
    extra_hosts:
      - "example.com:100.0.0.201"
    volumes:
      - katana-secrets:/secrets
      - katana-static:/warriorframework_py3/static
      - katana-wapps:/warriorframework_py3/katana/wapps
      - katana-wui:/warriorframework_py3/katana/wui
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    environment:
      DB_HOST: katana-db
      DB_NAME: warrior
      DB_USER: *****
      DB_PASSWORD: *****
  migration:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    image: warrior_deployment_backend
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c"]
    command: ["
      python /warriorframework_py3/katana/manage.py collectstatic --noinput;
      python /warriorframework_py3/katana/manage.py makemigrations;
      python /warriorframework_py3/katana/manage.py migrate;
      echo \"from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); x = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', '', 'warriorframework') if not User.objects.filter(username='admin').exists() else User.objects.get(username='admin'); x.set_password('warriorframework'); x.save()\" | python /warriorframework_py3/katana/manage.py shell;
      "]
    volumes:
      - katana-static:/warriorframework_py3/static
      - katana-wapps:/warriorframework_py3/katana/wapps
      - katana-wui:/warriorframework_py3/katana/wui
    environment:
      DB_HOST: katana-db
      DB_NAME: warrior
      DB_USER: warrior
      DB_PASSWORD: qwerty
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile_nginx
    image: warrior_deployment_frontend
    volumes:
      - katana-static:/warriorframework_py3/static
      - nginx-secrets:/secrets
    ports:
      - "9443:8443"
    labels:
      kompose.service.expose: "true"

volumes:
  katana-static:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/katana-static
  katana-wapps:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/wapps
  katana-wui:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/wui
  nginx-secrets:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/nginx-secrets
  katana-secrets:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/katana-secrets
```

when i run:

`sudo kompose up --provider openshift`

The error is as follows:

`FATA Error while deploying application: persistentvolumeclaims "katana-static" already exists`

The full console logs are as follows:

```
INFO Building image 'warrior_deployment_backend' from directory 'warrior_docker_deployment'
INFO Image 'warrior_deployment_backend' from directory 'warrior_docker_deployment' built successfully
INFO Pushing image 'warrior_deployment_backend:latest'
INFO Multiple authentication credentials detected. Will try each configuration.
INFO Attempting authentication credentials 'docker-registry-default.router.default.svc.cluster.local
INFO Successfully pushed image 'warrior_deployment_backend:latest'
INFO Building image 'warrior_deployment_frontend' from directory 'warrior_docker_deployment'
INFO Image 'warrior_deployment_frontend' from directory 'warrior_docker_deployment' built successfully
INFO Pushing image 'warrior_deployment_frontend:latest' to registry 
INFO Multiple authentication credentials detected. Will try each configuration.
INFO Attempting authentication credentials 'docker-registry-default.router.default.svc.cluster.local
INFO Successfully pushed image 'warrior_deployment_frontend:latest' 
INFO We are going to create OpenShift DeploymentConfigs, Services and PersistentVolumeClaims for your Dockerized application.
If you need different kind of resources, use the 'kompose convert' and 'oc create -f' commands instead.

INFO Deploying application in "rak-warrior-ui" namespace
INFO Successfully created Service: backend
INFO Successfully created Service: frontend
INFO Successfully created DeploymentConfig: backend
INFO Successfully created ImageStream: backend
INFO Successfully created PersistentVolumeClaim: katana-secrets of size 100Mi. If your cluster has dynamic storage provisioning, you don't have to do anything. Otherwise you have to create PersistentVolume to make PVC work
INFO Successfully created PersistentVolumeClaim: katana-static of size 100Mi. If your cluster has dynamic storage provisioning, you don't have to do anything. Otherwise you have to create PersistentVolume to make PVC work
INFO Successfully created PersistentVolumeClaim: katana-wapps of size 100Mi. If your cluster has dynamic storage provisioning, you don't have to do anything. Otherwise you have to create PersistentVolume to make PVC work
INFO Successfully created PersistentVolumeClaim: katana-wui of size 100Mi. If your cluster has dynamic storage provisioning, you don't have to do anything. Otherwise you have to create PersistentVolume to make PVC work
INFO Successfully created DeploymentConfig: frontend
INFO Successfully created ImageStream: frontend
INFO Successfully created Route: frontend
FATA Error while deploying application: persistentvolumeclaims "katana-static" already exists
```

As per my observation/analysis, the error can be due to following:-

kompose might be wrongly interpreting the shared volumes. If i explain this more clearly, it is like "katana-static" is a shared volume that is used by frontend,backend, and migration containers. kompose does the following steps(here I'm focusing only on shared volume: katana-static)

1. The kompose up will read the docker-compose.yml
2. Now the first container is backend, so there it finds katana-static under volumes, so it creates the volume.
3. Next it goes to next container and finds katana-static again, so it tries to create again
4. Since it tries to create the shared persistent volume katana-static again, which already exists it throws error which we are facing.

If this is actually what is happening then what can the fix for this? or else what is causing this error?

If there is any other forum where i can ask this question please share the link in comment section.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Those volumes look like you're trying to inject significant parts of the application code using volumes.  It'd be better to build these into the images directly, and not try to share a static asset tree across pods.  (Even in plain Docker, this is hard to maintain; if you change static content, it will never update an extant volume.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be with local volumes

```
volumes:
  katana-static:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/katana-static
  katana-wapps:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/wapps
  katana-wui:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/wui
  nginx-secrets:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/nginx-secrets
  katana-secrets:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/local-persist/data/warrior/katana-secrets
```

local volumes dont work in openshift. i suggest you to convert docker-compose into kubernetes YAMLs using 'kompose convert' command.

Then review and update the pvc and pv's. Then finally deploy resources one by one

Comment: I got your point, but how do you build the images?, previously the build was happening in ```kompose up``` step. But now we are using the converted files and performing the ```oc create```.